How can I keep the <form> after using wire:click?
I am using Laravel and the Filament v2 library to create a comment form for users. The comment creation process and saving to the database work well, but after submitting a comment through the form, my form disappears and displays the form with an ID like this:
<wire:id="DNrNhGuRgFdKHDeyOPSZ">

Here is the code to call my form:
<div class="p-0 space-y-6 relative mt-2">
    <form>
        {{ $this->form}}
        <div class="flex items-center space-x-2 rounded-b absolute btn-bar">
            <button wire:click="submit" type="button" wire:loading.attr="disabled"
                    class="btn-reply disabled:bg-slate-300 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none font-medium rounded text-sm px-5 py-1.5 text-center">
                {{ $reply?->id ? 'Gửi' : 'Gửi' }}
            </button>
            @if($reply?->id)
                <button type="button" wire:click="cancel()" wire:loading.attr="disabled" class="btn-cancel text-white bg-slate-700 disabled:bg-slate-300 hover:bg-slate-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-slate-300 font-medium rounded text-sm px-5 py-1.5 text-center dark:bg-slate-600 dark:hover:bg-slate-700 dark:focus:ring-slate-800">
                    Bỏ qua
                </button>
            @endif
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

and here is the code to create the form and its submit functions
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Discussion;

use App\Core\NotificationConstants;
use App\Core\PointsConstants;
use App\Forms\Components\MentionsRichEditor;
use App\Jobs\CalculateUserPointsJob;
use App\Jobs\DispatchNotificationsJob;
use App\Models\Discussion;
use App\Models\Reply as ReplyModel;
use App\Models\User;
use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Filament\Forms\Components\RichEditor;
use Filament\Forms\Concerns\InteractsWithForms;
use Filament\Forms\Contracts\HasForms;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\Component;

class Reply extends Component implements HasForms
{
    use InteractsWithForms;

    public Discussion $discussion;
    public ReplyModel|null $reply = null;

    public function mount(): void
    {
        $data = [];
        if ($this->reply) {
            $data['content'] = $this->reply->content;
        }
        $this->form->fill($data);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.discussion.reply');
    }

    protected function getFormSchema(): array
    {
        return [
            MentionsRichEditor::make('content')
                ->label('')
                ->disableAllToolbarButtons()
                ->enableToolbarButtons([
                    'bold',
                    'strike',
                    'italic',
                    'blockquote',
                    'codeBlock',
                    'attachFiles',
                    'orderedList',
                    'bulletList'
                ])
                ->placeholder('Bạn nghĩ gì về chủ đề này?')
                ->mentionsItems(
                    User::all()
                        ->map(
                            fn (User $user) => [
                                'key' => $user->name,
                                'link' => route('user.index', [
                                    'user' => $user,
                                    'slug' => Str::slug($user->name)
                                ])
                            ])
                        ->toArray()
                )
                ->required()
        ];
    }

    public function submit(): void
    {
        $data = $this->form->getState();
        if ($this->reply) {
            $this->reply->content = $data['content'];
            $this->reply->save();
            $message = 'Reply updated successfully';
        } else {
            ReplyModel::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'discussion_id' => $this->discussion->id,
                'content' => $data['content']
            ]);
            $message = 'Reply added successfully';
            dispatch(new DispatchNotificationsJob(auth()->user(), NotificationConstants::POST_IN_DISCUSSION->value, $this->discussion));
        }
        Filament::notify('success', $message);
        $this->emit('replyAdded');
        $this->emit('replyUpdated');
        if ($this->reply) {
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('replyUpdated');
        } else {
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('replyAdded');

            dispatch(new CalculateUserPointsJob(user: auth()->user(), source: $this->reply, type: PointsConstants::NEW_REPLY->value));
        }
        if ($this->reply) {
            $data['content'] = $this->reply->content;
        }
        $this->form->fill($data);
    }

    public function cancel(): void
    {
        $this->emit('replyUpdated');
    }
}

This is the image of my form when the page loads
Does anyone have a solution for this? Please help me.
Thank you so much!
I have searched Filament’s documentation but couldn’t find a solution. I’m sorry, as I’m new to this library. Please help me.
